# Why is my queue working without dequeue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read jquery docs many times but fail to understand the dequeue method. Consider the following example:

```js
var div = $(".div");



div.animate({
  height: "200px"
}, 3000).queue(function(){
  console.log("3 seconds passed and I show off without dequeue");  
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```

When you run this script you'd see that the function inside `queue` fires after 3 seconds but I have not `dequeued` it. jQuery says dequeue takes the function out of queue and then executes it. But if the function can execute without dequeue then what's the use dequeue?

Comment: Have you tried adding another callback function or animation after that?

Comment: @Bergi No but why should I add another animation after that?

Comment: Because you'd see that the *next* queue item is not called / started when you lack the `dequeue` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dequeue()` is called to keep the queue being executed, if you have two animations, the second won't be called if you don't use it. Check the next example, based on your code: the first div has .dequeue commented so only one animation is executed.

```js
var divClass = $(".div");
divClass.animate({
  height: "50px"
}, 500).queue(function(){
 
  //$(this).dequeue();
}).animate({height: "100px"},500);

var div = $("div");
div.animate({
  height: "50px"
}, 500).queue(function(){
  
  $(this).dequeue();
}).animate({height: "100px"},500);
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">First DIV</div>
<span>HELLO</span>
<div>Second DIV</div>
```